# SQL query records containing all items in list

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, relational-division

I have the following tables:

### MOVIES

```
  MOVIE_ID TITLE
---------- -----------------------------
         1 The Shawshank Redemption
         2 The Godfather
         3 The Godfather: Part II
         4 The Dark Knight
         5 Pulp Fiction
         6 The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
         7 Schindler's List
         8 Angry Men
         9 Fight Club
        10 Inception
        11 Forrest Gump
```

### DIRECTORS

```
DIRECTOR_ID NAME
----------- -------------------------
          1 Tim Robbins
          2 Morgan Freeman
          3 Marlon Brando
          4 Al Pachino
          5 Robert De Niro
          6 Christian Bale
          7 Heath Ledger
          8 John Travola
          9 Uma Thurman
         10 Clint Eastwood
         11 Eli Wallach
```

### Direct

```
  MOVIE_ID DIRECTOR_ID
---------- -----------
         1           1
         1           2
         2           3
         2           4
         3           4
         3           5
         4           6
         4           7
         5           8
         5           9
         6          10
```

I'd like a query that returns all movies that have directors x, y and z as their director:

Example:

> If I look for a movie with **Al Pachino** and **Clint Eastwood**, it
> should return **nothing** because I don't have a movie that has both of
> them as it's director.
>
> However if I were to look for a movie with **Tim Robbins** and **Morgan
> Freeman**, it should return **The Shawshank Redemption**

Please suggest alternative if it cannot be done using the above design.

I've attempted it but my query will return results :(

```
SELECT m.title FROM Movie m 
WHERE m.movie_id IN (
      SELECT d.movie_id FROM Direct d
      WHERE d.director_id IN (
           SELECT director_id FROM Director dir 
           WHERE name IN('Clint Eastwood', 'Al Pachino')));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to achieve this, viz to group, filter and then count the directors:

```
SELECT m.title 
FROM Movie m
     INNER JOIN Direct md
     on md.movie_id = m.movie_id
     INNER JOIN Directors d
     on md.director_id = d.director_id
WHERE 
     d.name IN('Clint Eastwood', 'Al Pachino')
GROUP BY m.title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.director_id) = 2;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26cac/1)

{Out of interest, aren't these the actors in the movies?}

Comment: It was just for illustrative purpose

Comment: On the basis that no director can direct the same movie twice, the DISTINCT operator *should* be redundant

Comment: @Strawberry hmm ... maybe a director's cut re-release? More seriously, OP hasn't posted the DDL, so without a UNIQUE KEY or PK constraints, better safe than sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With the IN operator, your query returns movies that have *any* of these directors.

You have to check for each director separately:

```
SELECT *
FROM Movie
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id
                   FROM Direct
                   WHERE director_id = (SELECT director_id
                                        FROM Directors
                                        WHERE name = 'Clint Eastwood'))
  AND movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id
                   FROM Direct
                   WHERE director_id = (SELECT director_id
                                        FROM Directors
                                        WHERE name = 'Al Pachino'))
```

Alternatively, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to construct a list of movie IDs for both directors:

```
SELECT *
FROM Movie
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id
                   FROM Direct
                   WHERE director_id = (SELECT director_id
                                        FROM Directors
                                        WHERE name = 'Clint Eastwood')
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT movie_id
                   FROM Direct
                   WHERE director_id = (SELECT director_id
                                        FROM Directors
                                        WHERE name = 'Al Pachino'))
```

Alternatively, get all records for these two directors from the `Direct` table, and then group by the movie to be able to count the directors per movie; we need to have two left:

```
SELECT *
FROM Movie
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id
                   FROM Direct
                   WHERE director_id IN (SELECT director_id
                                         FROM Directors
                                         WHERE name IN ('Clint Eastwood',
                                                        'Al Pachino')
                   GROUP BY movie_id
                   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one

```
   ;with cte as (      
    select m.title, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by m.title order by dir.name) rn 
    from Movie m
    inner join Direct d on m.movie_id = d.movie_id
    inner join Director dir on dir.DIRECTOR_ID = d.director_id
    where dir.name IN ('Clint Eastwood', 'Al Pachino')
    )
    select * from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as well with SQLite:

```
SELECT title
 FROM movie NATURAL JOIN direct NATURAL JOIN directors
 GROUP BY title
  HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(name)  LIKE '%Morgan Freeman%' AND GROUP_CONCAT(name)  LIKE '%Tim  Robbins%'
;
```

Test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b00b5/2/0)